# Difference between "ImportError: DLL load failed" and "No module named .."

Tags: python, py2exe

where is the difference between the errors `ImportError: DLL load failed` and `No module named ..`?

Because I got a problem:

Two files in the same directory. Both scripts tries to import MyModule.

Script 1: it works (called this via python)

Script 2: DLL load failed  (called this via executeable)

What does `DLL load failed` mean? This is not the same like "no module found"? How can I solve it?

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you specify which libraries to pack into the `.exe`? Showing the setup and what you do with py2exe will be helpful, otherwise we'll have to take out the crystal ball and try to divine what's wrong giving you generic advice.

Answer (score 1):

DLL load failed should be that it does find the DLL but not all the dependencies of that DLL and thus it fails to load. If you are on windows you can use something like http://www.dependencywalker.com/ to check the DLL's dependencies and make sure that at the moment of the import from the executable the environment is properly set up so all of them can be found.